# Wrapping a span tag with an a tag with a href target same as the text of the span

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My document has many *[span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Div_and_span)* tags like the following:

```
<span class='myClass'>aaa</span>
```

I would like to turn each of them into the following:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/aaa" onclick="myfunc();"><span class='myClass'>aaa</span></a>
```

Is there a way to do this? It could be plain JavaScript or jQuery (3.1.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, you can iterate all `.myClass` elements using `.each()`, then wrap them using `.wrap()`

```js
$(".myClass").each( function() {
  $(this).wrap('<a href="http://www.example.com/' + $(this).text() + '" onclick="myfunc();" />');
});

console.log($(".myClass").parent())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class='myClass'>aaa</span>
<span class='myClass'>bbb</span>
<span class='myClass'>ccc</span>
<span class='myClass'>ddd</span>
```

https://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```js
const els=document.querySelectorAll("span.myClass");
els.forEach((el)=>{
   const t=el.textContent;
   const aEl=document.createElement("a");
   aEl.href=`http://example.com/${t}`;
   aEl.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true))
   el.parentElement.insertBefore(aEl,el);
   el.remove()
})
```